# How to delete all duplicate node with the same field value in drupal type

Tags: 8, entities, database

I need to bulk delete the duplicate nodes based on the same field and keep just one node.

How can I do that ?

I tried that :

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', "diffusion");
$query->groupBy('field_id_diffusion');
//$query->having('COUNT(field_id_diffusion) >= 1');
$duplicate = $query->execute();
```

Comment: how many nodes do you have?

Comment: Depending on the count of nodes, it might be best to do this as a batch op. Or could you use Views, add the field as a exposed filter, and bulk delete the result list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your nodes are not  too many you can achieve it by something like  following   :

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', "diffusion");
$query->groupBy('field_id_diffusion');
$nids = $query->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);

$diffusion_checklist = [];
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   $diff_id = $node->get('field_id_diffusion')->value;

   if (!in_array($diff_id ,$diffusion_checklist)) {
     $diffusion_checklist[] = $diff_id;
   }
   else {
     $node->delete();
   }
}
```

And if you have too many nodes  another solution is implement the same strategy with setup a [batch operations](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!form.inc/group/batch/8.2.x)

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. We have 80.000 nodes to check => I don't know what's your definition of too many but it's kinda huge for me...

Comment: @injetkilo my solution is worked, 80,000 is not too many. just set max_execution_time  to something like 360 - 720 temporary ( it's dependence on your CPU and Memory limit).